# Sharepoint 2019 - modify search result item template to return Office URI Schemes

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, display-template

I am looking for a way to open word, excel, ppt files in a local client application.
For any mysterious reasons that work in document libraries but not in search results.
I know that it works if I manually add the [micrsoft URI sheme](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes) to a file-URL.

So my idea was to modify the search result item template (HoverPanel) output from the "open"-link. So that the "open"-Link does return the Microsoft Uri schema instead of the plain file-URL.
The reason why I choose this way is to avoid client-side javascript code like in cewp or script-editor-webpart.

I am definitely no javascript professional, so maybe anybody can tell me whether that is possible or not. And of course, if it's possible, a code example would be very nice ^_^

Below the example content of Item_powerPoint.html and Item_PowerPoint_HoverPanel.html.

### Item_PowerPoint.html

```
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"> 
<head>
<title>PowerPoint-Element</title>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
<mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string">Zeigt ein auf Microsoft PowerPoint-Dokumente abgestimmtes Ergebnis an.</mso:MasterPageDescription>
<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#SearchResults;#</mso:TargetControlType>
<mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Title':'Title','Path':'Path','Description':'Description','EditorOWSUSER':'EditorOWSUSER','LastModifiedTime':'LastModifiedTime','CollapsingStatus':'CollapsingStatus','DocId':'DocId','HitHighlightedSummary':'HitHighlightedSummary','HitHighlightedProperties':'HitHighlightedProperties','FileExtension':'FileExtension','ViewsLifeTime':'ViewsLifeTime','ParentLink':'ParentLink','FileType':'FileType','IsContainer':'IsContainer','SecondaryFileExtension':'SecondaryFileExtension','DisplayAuthor':'DisplayAuthor','ServerRedirectedURL':'ServerRedirectedURL','SectionNames':'SectionNames','SectionIndexes':'SectionIndexes','ServerRedirectedEmbedURL':'ServerRedirectedEmbedURL','ServerRedirectedPreviewURL':'ServerRedirectedPreviewURL'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Item_PowerPoint">
<!--#_ 
        if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl)){
            var id = ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
            var itemId = id + Srch.U.Ids.item;
            var hoverId = id + Srch.U.Ids.hover;
            var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_PowerPoint_HoverPanel.js";
            $setResultItem(itemId, ctx.CurrentItem);
            ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getShowHoverPanelCallback(itemId, hoverId, hoverUrl);
            ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getHideHoverPanelCallback();
            ctx.CurrentItem.csr_OpenApp = "powerpoint";
_#-->
            <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(itemId) =#_" name="Item" data-displaytemplate="PowerPointItem" class="ms-srch-item" onmouseover="_#= ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback =#_" onmouseout="_#= ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback =#_">
<!--#_
                if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem.ServerRedirectedPreviewURL))
                {
                    ctx.CurrentItem.csr_PreviewImage = ctx.CurrentItem.ServerRedirectedPreviewURL;
                    ctx.CurrentItem.csr_PathLength = Srch.U.pathTruncationLengthWithPreview;
                }
                ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Icon = Srch.U.getIconUrlByFileExtension(ctx.CurrentItem);
_#-->
                _#=ctx.RenderBody(ctx)=#_
                <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(hoverId) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-outerContainer"></div>
            </div>
<!--#_
        }
_#-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Item_PowerPoint_HoverPanel.html

```
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"> 
<head>
<title>PowerPoint-Daraufzeigebereich</title>

<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
<mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string">Zeigt einen auf Microsoft PowerPoint-Dokumente abgestimmten Ergebnisdaraufzeigebereich an.</mso:MasterPageDescription>
<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#SearchHoverPanel;#</mso:TargetControlType>
<mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Title':'Title','Path':'Path','Description':'Description','EditorOWSUSER':'EditorOWSUSER','LastModifiedTime':'LastModifiedTime','CollapsingStatus':'CollapsingStatus','DocId':'DocId','HitHighlightedSummary':'HitHighlightedSummary','HitHighlightedProperties':'HitHighlightedProperties','FileExtension':'FileExtension','ViewsLifeTime':'ViewsLifeTime','ParentLink':'ParentLink','FileType':'FileType','IsContainer':'IsContainer','SecondaryFileExtension':'SecondaryFileExtension','DisplayAuthor':'DisplayAuthor','ServerRedirectedURL':'ServerRedirectedURL','SectionNames':'SectionNames','SectionIndexes':'SectionIndexes','ServerRedirectedEmbedURL':'ServerRedirectedEmbedURL','ServerRedirectedPreviewURL':'ServerRedirectedPreviewURL'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Item_PowerPoint_HoverPanel">
<!--#_
        var i = 0;
        var wacurlExist = !Srch.U.e(ctx.CurrentItem.ServerRedirectedURL) && !Srch.U.e(ctx.CurrentItem.ServerRedirectedEmbedURL);
        var id = ctx.CurrentItem.csr_id;
        ctx.CurrentItem.csr_FileType = Srch.Res.file_PowerPoint;
        ctx.CurrentItem.csr_ShowFollowLink = true;
        ctx.CurrentItem.csr_ShowViewLibrary = true;
        ctx.currentItem_IsOfficeDocument = true;
_#-->
        <div class="ms-srch-hover-innerContainer ms-srch-hover-wacSize" id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.inner) =#_">
            <div class="ms-srch-hover-arrowBorder" id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.arrowBorder) =#_"></div>
            <div class="ms-srch-hover-arrow" id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.arrow) =#_"></div>
            <div class="ms-srch-hover-content" id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.content) =#_" data-displaytemplate="PowerPointHoverPanel">
                <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.header) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-header">
                    _#= ctx.RenderHeader(ctx) =#_
                </div>
                <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.body) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-body">
<!--#_
                    if(!Srch.U.n(ctx.CurrentItem.ServerRedirectedEmbedURL))
                    {
                        ctx.CurrentItem.csr_DataShown = true;
                        ctx.currentItem_ShowChangedBySnippet = true;
_#-->
                        <div class="ms-srch-hover-viewerContainer">
                            <iframe id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.viewer) =#_" src="_#= $urlHtmlEncodeString(ctx.CurrentItem.ServerRedirectedEmbedURL) =#_" scrolling="no" frameborder="0px" class="ms-srch-hover-viewer"></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ms-srch-hover-wacImageContainer">
                            <img id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.preview) =#_" alt="_#= $htmlEncode(Srch.Res.item_Alt_Preview) =#_" onload="this.parentNode.style.display='block';" />
                        </div>
<!--#_
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ctx.CurrentItem.csr_ShowLastModifiedTime = true;
                        ctx.CurrentItem.csr_ShowAuthors = true; 
                    }

                    if(!Srch.U.e(ctx.CurrentItem.SectionNames))
                    {
                        ctx.CurrentItem.csr_DataShown = true;
_#-->
                        <div class="ms-srch-hover-subTitle"><h3 class="ms-soften">_#= $htmlEncode(Srch.Res.hp_SectionHeadings) =#_</h3></div>
<!--#_
                        var sectionNames = Srch.U.getArray(ctx.CurrentItem.SectionNames);

                        var sectionIndexes = Srch.U.getArray(ctx.CurrentItem.SectionIndexes);
                        if(!Srch.U.n(sectionIndexes) && sectionIndexes.length != sectionNames.length)
                        {
                            sectionIndexes = null;
                        }

                        var hitHighlightedSectionNames = Srch.U.getHighlightedProperty(id, ctx.CurrentItem, "sectionnames");
                        if(!Srch.U.n(hitHighlightedSectionNames) && hitHighlightedSectionNames.length != sectionNames.length)
                        {
                            hitHighlightedSectionNames = null;
                        }

                        var numberOfSectionsToDisplay = Math.min(Srch.SU.maxLinesForMultiValuedProperty, sectionNames.length);
                        var sectionsToDisplay = new Array();

                        var usingHitHighlightedSectionNames = Srch.SU.getSectionsForDisplay(
                            hitHighlightedSectionNames,
                            numberOfSectionsToDisplay,
                            sectionsToDisplay);

                        for(i = 0; i < sectionsToDisplay.length; ++i)
                        {
                            var index = sectionsToDisplay[i];
                            if(Srch.U.n(index))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            var tooltipEncoded = $htmlEncode(sectionNames[index]);

                            var htmlEncodedSectionName = "";
                            if(usingHitHighlightedSectionNames)
                            {
                                htmlEncodedSectionName = hitHighlightedSectionNames[index];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                htmlEncodedSectionName = tooltipEncoded;
                            }
_#-->
                            <div class="ms-srch-hover-text ms-srch-ellipsis" id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.sectionName + i) =#_" title="_#= tooltipEncoded =#_">
<!--#_
                                if(!Srch.U.n(sectionIndexes) && sectionIndexes.length >= i && !Srch.U.e(sectionIndexes[index]) && wacurlExist)
                                {
                                    var encodedSlideIndex = "&wdSlideIndex=" + $urlKeyValueEncode(sectionIndexes[index]);
_#-->
                                    <a clicktype="HoverSection" linkIndex="_#= $htmlEncode(i) =#_" href="_#= $urlHtmlEncodeString(ctx.CurrentItem.ServerRedirectedURL + encodedSlideIndex) =#_" target="_blank">
                                        _#= htmlEncodedSectionName =#_
                                    </a>
<!--#_
                                }
                                else
                                {
_#-->
                                    _#= htmlEncodedSectionName =#_
<!--#_
                                }
_#-->
                            </div>
<!--#_
                        }
                    }
_#-->
                    _#= ctx.RenderBody(ctx) =#_
                </div>
                <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.actions) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-actions">
                    _#= ctx.RenderFooter(ctx) =#_
                </div>
            </div>
<!--#_
            if(!Srch.U.n(ctx.CurrentItem.ServerRedirectedEmbedURL)){
                AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function(){
                    HP.loadViewer(ctx.CurrentItem.id, ctx.CurrentItem.id + HP.ids.inner, ctx.CurrentItem.id + HP.ids.viewer, ctx.CurrentItem.id + HP.ids.preview, ctx.CurrentItem.ServerRedirectedEmbedURL, ctx.CurrentItem.ServerRedirectedPreviewURL);
                });
            }
_#-->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```